# Is AfterPropertiesSet the correct place to load staticList?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I'm loading a static list from database in the afterPropertiesSet() method.

In this class I use a static list in a lot of methods, so I don't want to load this list always from database.

The code is:

```
 private Collection<Country> countries= null;

 [...] // Use of countries in many methods

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    // Load countries types
    countries = getAddressService().loadCountries();

}
```

Is a good practice load collections in afterPropertiesSet()? which option would be better? I don't want to do multiples calls to DB.

Comment: what's `static`?

Comment: So the list isn't actually static but loaded from the db and then cached? In that case wouldn't a cache that loads the list on demand (e.g. on a cache miss) be the easier to use option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a simple cache:

```
@Cacheable
public Collection<Country> getCountries() throws Exception {
    return getAddressService().loadCountries();
}
```

And then you can access them with `service.getCountries()`. Only the first invocation will load from the database. All successive calls get the collection from the cache.